# Problem with saving mp3 files in internalStorage

Tags: java, android, mp3, ringtone, internal-storage

Hello I working on a ringtone application and  in my app, I have many ringtone mp3 files 
in my app I download an save mp3 files into internal Storage with below code :

```
   ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);
    File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(context.getFilesDir().getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    File parent = new File(directory, "RingTones");
    final String songPath = "/" + arrayListNames.get(pos).getSoundLink() + ".mp3";
    final String loc = parent + songPath;
    final File checkFile = new File(parent, songPath);
```

and when I want to set mp3 file as a ringtone, the ringtone will be set and the mp3 file name will appear in Setting/Notification and Sound/ Ringtone but the sound is default phone sound. here is set ringtone code :

```
setRingtone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //<editor-fold desc="RingTones">
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, checkFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, arrayListNames.get(pos).getSoundLink()); //You will have to populate
                            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
                            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Band Name"); //You will have to populate this
                            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
                            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
                            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
                            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
                            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(checkFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + checkFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
                            Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
                            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                                    context,
                                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                                    newUri
                            );
                            setRingTonesDialog.dismiss();
                            //Ringtone set

                        }
                    });
```

I think it's because of saving file location in internal storage
what should I change?

Comment: The media store will not be happy with your apps private getFilesDir() i think.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Change the dir.

Comment: can you send me an example as an Answer?

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() getExternalFilesDir().